# Remove duplicates in list based upon multiple conditions

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a list with duplicate `Student` objects that I want to clean up. Objects in the list should be removed if they have both the same name and ID.

Can someone help with the Comparator implementation below?

```
public class RemoveDuplicate {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ArrayList students = new ArrayList();
    students.add(new Student("Student1", "1000", "1"));
    students.add(new Student("Student2", "1001", "2"));
    students.add(new Student("Student3", "1002", "3"));
    students.add(new Student("Student4", "1001", "4"));
    students.add(new Student("Student1", "1003", "45"));
    students.add(new Student("Student1", "1000", "46"));
    students.add(new Student("Student4", "1001", "47"));
    Set set = new TreeSet(new StudentsComparator());
    set.addAll(students);
    final ArrayList newList = new ArrayList(set);
    System.out.println(newList);
}
}
class StudentsComparator implements Comparator<Student> {
@Override
public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
    System.out.println(s1 + "," + s2);
    if (s1.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(s2.getId())) {
        if (s1.getNum().equalsIgnoreCase(s2.getNum())) {
            System.out.println("return0");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
}
```

Actual output :

```
Name=Student1   Id=1000   Num=1, 
Name=Student2   Id=1001   Num=2, 
Name=Student3   Id=1002   Num=3, 
Name=Student4   Id=1001   Num=4, 
Name=Student1   Id=1003   Num=45, 
Name=Student1   Id=1000   Num=46, 
Name=Student4   Id=1001   Num=47]
```

Expected output :

```
Name=Student1   Id=1000   Num=1, 
Name=Student2   Id=1001   Num=2, 
Name=Student3   Id=1002   Num=3, 
Name=Student4   Id=1001   Num=4, 
Name=Student1   Id=1003   Num=45]
```

thanks

Comment: Which values do `getId` and `getNum` return from `Student`?  Why isn't there a case where `compare` returns a negative number to indicate that s1 < s2?

Comment: That isn’t a valid comparator. It can return 1 but it can never return a negative number, so it isn’t antisymmetric.

Comment: Rewrote description for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Comparator` implementation is not correct as the current object is always equal or greater than the compared one (you never return negative value).
So the symmetric rule is not respected :

> The implementor must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) ==
>   -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y.

Whatever, to remove duplicates the `TreeSet` is inappropriate if you don't want to sort them.

Instead of, override `equals()` and `hashCode()` in your `Student` class and add your elements (originally in a `ArrayList`) in a `LinkedHashSet` to keep the actual order.

```
final List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
students.add(new Student("Student1", "1000", "1"));
students.add(new Student("Student2", "1001", "2"));
...
LinkedHashSet<Student> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(students);
```

Comment: Why is using a TreeSet useless for removing duplicates?

Comment: @cpp beginner I had reworded : "inappropriate" for the use case.

Answer (score 0):

Your [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) breaks the comparator contract:

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Also, the add in the `TreeSet` takes `log(n)` (which ins't that bad, specially for not that large collections), If you can override `equals` and `hashcode` that would be normally a better option.

But, if you want to have a custom comparator generated dinamically, or cannot/want to override `equals` and `hashcode`, you can use the functions `comparing` and `thenComparing` that provides the java `Comparator`.

```
Comparator<Student> studentComparator = Comparator
        .comparing((Student student) -> student.getId().toLowerCase())
        .thenComparing((Student student) -> student.getNum().toLowerCase());
```

This comparator functions are *generally* easier to use, and *perhaps* less error prone. You can use it in the `TreeSet` as normal.

This comparator however is not null safe, you need to pass `Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())` as second argument to allow the comparation of nulls. And also check the string before call `toLowerCase()`.

You can use some helper methods (Or create a custom comparator that define something similar to):

```
public static String handleCase(String str) {
    return str != null ? str.toLowerCase() : null;
}
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<T> nullComparator() {
    return Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder());
}
```

And for instance if `num` is a nullable property, you can use:

```
Comparator<Student> studentComparator = Comparator
    .comparing((Student student) -> handleCase(student.getId()))
    .thenComparing((Student student) -> handleCase(student.getNum()), nullComparator());
```

Finally, if you want to access this comparator from 'anywhere', you can wrap the definition in a comparator, as a `final` field, or `static` for a singleton, or just as a `final static` field in a helper class for custom comparators.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the running code for your specific problem.

**Student Class**

```
public class Student {

private String name;
private String id;
private String num;



public Student(String name, String id, String num) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.num = num;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getNum() {
    return num;
}
public void setNum(String num) {
    this.num = num;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student [name=" + name + ", id=" + id + ", num=" + num + "]";
}
```

**Main class**

```
public class RemoveDuplicate {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ArrayList students = new ArrayList();
    students.add(new Student("Student1", "1000", "1"));
    students.add(new Student("Student2", "1001", "2"));
    students.add(new Student("Student3", "1002", "3"));
    students.add(new Student("Student4", "1001", "4"));
    students.add(new Student("Student1", "1003", "45"));
    students.add(new Student("Student1", "1000", "46"));
    students.add(new Student("Student4", "1001", "47"));

    Set set = new TreeSet(new StudentsComparator());
    set.addAll(students);
    final ArrayList newList = new ArrayList(set);
    System.out.println(newList);
}
}
class StudentsComparator implements Comparator<Student> {
@Override
    public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
      if (s1.getId().compareTo(s2.getId()) == 0) 
         return s1.getName().compareTo(s2.getName());
      else 
         return s1.getId().compareTo(s2.getId());
    }
}
```